Exhausting humidity and balancing air temperature throughout house
I currently have two issues in my house that I am wondering how to address, and was thinking that I could solve both with a similar solution. I recently bought a house that had insufficient bathroom exhausts which caused humidity to accumulate easily. The main bathroom has no direct exhaust while the second bathroom has no exhaust to the outside at all.
                ▲                                 
                │                                 
                │                                 
────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────
                │                                 
                │ Exhaust through roof            
                │                                 
                │                          ▲      
                │                          │      
       ┌────────┴───┐     Exhaust to attic │      
       │            │                      │      
       │   Toilet   │       ┌──────────────┴──┐   
       │            │       │                 │   
       └────────────┘       │   Bathroom 2    │   
              ▲             │                 │   
              │             └─────────────────┘   
    ┌─────────┴────────┐      
    │                  │           
    │    Bathroom      │                          
    │                  │                                                                     
    └──────────────────┘                          

To prevent further issues in the future, I would like to add additional bathroom exhausts to the single roof outlet using an inline duct fan and electrically-actuated dampers. The idea is that the fan would operate if any switch were on, and the dampers would be open for each individual respective switch.
                     ▲                       
                     │                       
─────────────────────┼───────────────────────
                     │                       
                     │                       
                 ┌───┴───┐                   
                 │       │                   
                 │  Fan  │                   
        ┌───────►│       │◄─────────┐        
        │        └───────┘          │        
        │            ▲              │        
        │            │              │        
        │            │              │        
  ┌─────┴────┐  ┌────┴─────┐   ┌────┴─────┐  
  │  Damper  │  │  Damper  │   │  Damper  │  
  └──────────┘  └──────────┘   └──────────┘  
        ▲             ▲              ▲       
        │             │              │       
        │             │              │       
  ┌─────┴────┐   ┌────┴───┐   ┌──────┴─────┐ 
  │          │   │        │   │            │ 
  │ Bathroom │   │ Toilet │   │ Bathroom 2 │ 
  │          │   │        │   │            │ 
  └──────────┘   └────────┘   └────────────┘ 

Would a setup like this alleviate my problem while meeting code? Furthermore, do you think there's another solution that may be easier? If this solution is sound, do you think it may be worth adding to individual bedrooms to help exhaust hot air during the summer? Some bedrooms have excess heat and the air pressure from the vents is not enough to evenly cool all rooms. The first floor is always significantly cooler. Would exhausting to the outside help pull cool air from the hallway/lower floors?

The way to balance the temperatures in the house is to move cooler air up from the lower floor to the upper floor, not to blow warm air out while drawing hot air in from outside. A modern solution you should perhaps consider that often operates more-or-less as you have drawn is a heat recovery ventilator or (particularly in a primary cooling climate) energy-recovery ventilator. That draws from multiple points (and bathrooms are common since they need the ventilation) and also draws in fresh air, passing though a heat exchanger, rather than just leaking fresh air in wherever.

Easier is exhausting the way every house does it, which is to an outside wall or eaves.  You install a fan in the ceiling connected to a switch on the wall.  If you have no other option then connecting all outlet ducts to the same rook through-connection would work.
I have no idea what your house is like in the summer, but a bathroom fan normally wouldn't pull enough air to cool a house, nor do you want it to - in the winter you're letting in cold air, in the summer hot air.
